# how to make \ref{number} print actual number and not the subsection number it references?

Tags: cross-referencing

### Example using \label and \ref

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%ext
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}  

see problem \ref{1} below and problem \ref{5} below.
    
\chapter{Differential equations}
\section{some section name}
\subsection{problem 1 from some book}
\label{1}

\subsection{problem 2 from some book}
\label{2}

OK.

\chapter{Differential equations second book}
\section{some section name}
\subsection{problem 1 from some second book}
\label{3}

OK.

\subsection{problem 2 from some second book}
\label{5}

OK.

\end{document}
```

Compiled using `lualatex foo.tex` gives

[image]

What needs to change to make `\ref{1}` prints the exact label name `1` in this case? So that the output reads

```
see problem 1 below and problem 5 below
```

I do not care for the subsection number when reading the PDF. I need to know the actual problem number itself, which is what is in what the argument of `\ref{1}` is meant to be.  Ofcourse clicking on the `ref` should still send me to the actual subsection in the document where the same `label` is located. I just want the display to be `1` exactly as it is.

The label I use is global counter which is increased by one for each problem.

I looked at number of documentation and so far not able to figure how. Do I need to use different package for this? Or do I need to use phantomsection? I need to emulate the output using \hyperlink and \hypertarget as shown below. Is this possible? if not, I will continue to use `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` in this case

### Example using `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}  

see problem \hyperlink{1}{1} below and problem \hyperlink{4}{4} below.
    
\chapter{Differential equations}
\section{some section name}
\subsection{problem 1 from some book}
\hypertarget{1}{}

\subsection{problem 2 from some book}
\hypertarget{2}{}

OK.

\chapter{Differential equations second book}
\section{some section name}
\subsection{problem 1 from some second book}
\hypertarget{3}{}

OK.

\subsection{problem 2 from some second book}
\hypertarget{4}{}

OK.

\end{document}
```

When the above is compiled, it gives the output I want

[image]

Or

### Example using \label and \hyperref

This was suggested thanks to gusbrs in comment

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%ext
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}  

see problem \hyperref[1]{1} below and problem \hyperref[4]{4} below.
    
\chapter{Differential equations}
\section{some section name}
\subsection{problem 1 from some book}
\label{1}

\subsection{problem 2 from some book}
\label{2}

OK.

\chapter{Differential equations second book}
\section{some section name}
\subsection{problem 1 from some second book}
\label{3}

OK.

\subsection{problem 2 from some second book}
\label{4}

OK.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using Tl 2021

Comment: If you have a second section in this document, there will be a "problem 1.2.1", same for chapter. If you refer to it by just "1", how will you know the difference between "1.1.1" and "1.2.1"?

Comment: problem number in `\label{n}` is unique for the whole document. it is a counter. These are `1,2,3,4,...`  and I want to do `\ref{1}` and `\ref{2}` etc... and have it display `1` and `2`. I do not care for the name of the section or subsection the problem is located in.  Similar to how `\href{url}{display text}` works. But `\ref` does not seem to take a display text.

Comment: Your MWE uses a subsection for "problem 1", and that is not an unique counter, since it will be reset every section and chapter. If you have indeed an unique counter, it is easy to define the printed representation of that counter to be by itself. But please provide a MWE which corresponds to that which you are describing then.

Comment: Btw, if you really have a counter which is not reset on sectioning levels, it probably does what you want by default.

Comment: But, if you don't, and really mean to use subsection for the purpose, you might do with a simple `\counterwithout{subsection}{section}`.

Comment: @gusbrs updated example.

Comment: You are still using subsection, I'm not sure I understand why. But, please tell me whether a "problem" is meant to be always a subsection, and if a subsection is not used for any other purposes. Also, please clarify if the "unique" counter is meant to be reset every chapter, as the example suggests.

Comment: @gusbrs  I used to do all this using `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` which accepts a "display" text option. But I was told in chat to use \ref and \label. Only to find this problem. Again, I do not care what section number or subsection number the problem is located in. I just want to do `see problem \ref{n}` and have it display `see problem n`. Where `n` is my own counter I increase from `1` to total number of problems in the book.

Comment: It does not matter if I use \subsection or \section. I just want `ref{1}` to print `1` regardless of where the anchor is located.

Comment: Well, I think I'm starting to understand what you want. I don't know of the discussion you had in chat, but as far as I can tell, that's not really what `\ref` is meant to do. I'd use `\hyperref[label]{text}`, in which case both `label` and `text` are your counter. Of course, that presumes you have set `\label{label}` somewhere.

Comment: @gusbrs  Yes, I had it all working OK before using \hypertarget and \hyperlink but the experts told me to change to \label and \ref but they did not tell me now \ref does not accept a "display" option. I thought \ref{1} will print `1`.  I have to go back to using \hypertarget and \hyperlink I guess. I just wasted long time changing my code for this. I did not notice that \ref{1} will print the actual subsubsection id where the label is located. I thought it will print `1` as is.

Comment: With `\hyperref` as mentioned, you'd not have to set `\hypertarget`, but that's about the only advantage. But there are probably other ways to deal with things. For example, if you defined a `problem` environment, you could handle it with a dedicated counter, without resetting, and then use `\ref`. But, if I understand correctly, this "counter" of yours is coming from some external source (possibly automated), in which case `\label`/`\ref` may not be the best tools after all.

Comment: @gusbrs yes, the counter is external. it is a program written in Maple which loops over all the problems from 1 to say 1,000. And it generates the Latex., So I know for each problem what is the problem number. But the actual problems can go anywhere is the document, in different sections depending on the book they came from. But the problem number is a global number over the whole book. Yes, it looks like \label and \ref will not work. I'll make another example showing how I did it before in few minutes.

Comment: If it is an external "counter", from LaTeX's perspective, the "reference" you want is "arbitrary text", and indeed, as far as I can tell, `\ref` is not the best tool. I'd personally use `\label` and `\hyperref[label]{text}`.

Comment: @gusbrs fyi, I added an example of how I was doing it before. Ok, so it looks like this can't be done using label and ref. I have to go back how I was doing it or will try what you suggested above using `\label` and `\hyperref[label]{text}` and see which is better.

Comment: @gusbrs I tried your method also and it works like \hypertarget and \hyperlink but it seems simpler.  OK then will not use ref and label for what I want. If you wanted to make this answer I will accept it to close this.

Comment: I just recalled a nice bonus from using `\label` here, see updated answer. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The advice you received to use `\label` and `\ref` is usually a sound one. But, as you explained in the comments, in your case, the "global counter" you'd like to refer to is not a LaTeX counter, but a counter generated elsewhere by an external program which generates your LaTeX document. That given, this "counter", from the perspective of the LaTeX referencing system, is "arbitrary text", in which case, the tools of `hyperref` seem the most appropriate ones.

Using `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` as you've been doing should work fine, but you may get some simplification by using `\label` and `\hyperref`, as in the example below. There is also a technical difference between using `\hypertarget`/`\hyperlink` vs. `\label`/ `\hyperref`: anchor placement. With the latter, the hyperlink anchor will be placed with the sectioning command, while with the former the anchor will be just bellow it. In practice, this means that with `\label`/ `\hyperref` you are sure to see the heading you'd expect when you follow the hyperlink.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

see problem \hyperref[1]{1} below and problem \hyperref[4]{4} below.

\chapter{Differential equations}
\section{some section name}
\subsection{problem 1 from some book}
\label{1}

\subsection{problem 2 from some book}
\label{2}

OK.

\chapter{Differential equations second book}
\section{some section name}
\subsection{problem 1 from some second book}
\label{3}

OK.

\subsection{problem 2 from some second book}
\label{4}

OK.

\end{document}
```

That doesn't mean you could not use `\label` and `\ref` in interesting ways, but for that, I'd say the counter should be handled on the LaTeX side, for example if you created a environment for your problems with a dedicated counter. But this would probably have some cost in adjusting the program that generates your document, whether it'd be worth it, I cannot tell, but you certainly can.  ;-)